# Setting up Eclipse IDE for Python and PHP development

Tags: python, eclipse, php

There are various versions of Eclipse IDE available at [Eclipse Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). Since, I am not concerned with Java development, I downloaded [the Eclipse Classic 3.7.1](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-371/indigosr1). Now, I want my IDE to be setup for Python and PHP development.

1) Have i downloaded the correct version ??

2) What tools should i download next.

NOTE : I haven't installed anything yet, just downloaded the classic version from Eclipse website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse 3.7.1 is the latest version, so it's fine. You'll also need:

- [PHP Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) and
- [PyDev](http://pydev.org/)

and of course you'll need some kind of PHP stack and a Python interpreter.